# AndroidStudio cannot run single parameterized test

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, junit, junit4

This is an example test with AndroidStudio 3.5

#### In my gradle files

- `testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"`
- `testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12`

#### Test class

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@LargeTest
@TestWithBackend
public class ParameterizedTestTest {
    @Parameter
    public String __testName;

    @Parameter(value = 1)
    public String _parameter;

    @Parameters(name="{0}")
    public static Collection<Object[]> initParameters() {
        // First parameter is the test name, second one the actual parameter
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                { "first",  "parameter1" },
                { "second", "parameter2" }
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void successfulTest() {
        Log.i("TAG", _parameter);
    }
}
```

#### Problems when executing tests

Running the whole test class using the double green arrow:

[image]

runs both tests as expected:

[image]

However, running a single test using the single green arrow:

[image]

results in "No tests were found":

[image]

If I don't use the parametrization, the single test execution also works. Is this a bug (if yes, where? Junit, IntelliJ or AndroidStudio?) or did I configure something wrong?

Comment: Does it work with JUnit 5? Is it possible to share sample project example?